# Questions on what a $k[x]$-module is, followup.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

This is a followup to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923895/not-really-sure-what-a-kx-module-is). I have tried reading some of the answers, and I don't really understand what they are saying in places.

1. > By the usual definition an $A$-module is an abelian group $V$ together with an action of $A$ on it. The action is given by a ring homomorphism $A \to \text{End}(V)$.

   I don't really understand why the action is given by a ring homomorphism $A \to \text{End}(V)$. Could anybody elaborate on this?
2. > Given a $k$-vector space $V$ together with a linear transformation $T$, we may give $V$ the structure of a $k[x]$-module as follows: $k$ acts on $V$ by scalar multiplication and $x$ acts on $V$ by $T$. This tells us how anything in $k[x]$ acts since everything in $k[x]$ is a sum of products of scalars and $x$'s.

   How does $x$ act on $V$ by $T$? And why does this tell us that how anything in $k[x]$ acts since everything in $k[x]$ is a sum of products of scalars and $x$'s?
3. > Conversely, given a $k[x]$-module $M$, we see that $M$ comes with an action of $k$, so is a vector space. Write $T$ for the map $M \to M$ given by multiplication by $x$. Then, since $k[x]$ is commutative, $T$ is $k$-linear for the aforementioned $k$ vector space structure.

   Why can we write $T$ for the map $M \to M$ given by multiplication by $x$? And why does $k[x]$ being commutative imply that $T$ is $k$-linear?
4. > Let $A = k[x]$ where $k$ is a field. Then an $A$-module is just a $k$-vector space equipped with a $k$-linear map $\widehat{x}: V \to V$.

   One point of confusion with this is as follows. So is a specific $A$-module equipped with a fixed linear map $\widehat{x}$ that corresponds to a specific element in $k[x]$? Or is $\widehat{x}$ allowed to vary as to correspond to all elements of $k[x]$? Or am I thinking of this in the wrong way and does this $\hat{x}$ correspond to $k[x]$ aggregate and not an element or elements in it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your background? You can't really learn math by asking questions on a Q&A site in a top-to-bottom fashion... Do you have a textbook or something you're studying from? Your #3 question is something you should know before asking yourself the question you linked...

Comment: In particular, do you know what an $R$-module is?

Comment: @Max I do, but that in within itself doesn't shine light on my questions.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In my opinion these are reasonable questions, modules are very difficult creatures to learn about. I certainly had a lot of difficulty grasping them a while back and needed to harass others with questions akin to OP's, even though the textbook I was using was very good.

Comment: @Harambe (ridiculous username) I'm not trying to discourage OP, I'm trying to tell him that it's worthwhile to understand the basics before tackling on more advanced stuff. Here, understanding why an $A$-module is the same thing as a morphism $A \to \operatorname{End}(V)$. Trying to learn math by asking an advanced question and then working in a top-to-bottom manner by asking a new question about each step you don't understand typically doesn't work -- you get overwhelmed quite quickly.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi There are multiple perspectives from which one can view modules at the introductory level, and some are intended to (and will) be understood better than others at first. But even having a passing understanding with some of the less elementary/concrete perspectives early on can help clarify one's thinking... it certainly did for me. So that's why I don't think there's anything wrong with a top-to-bottom manner here, if you can even call it that.

Comment: The trouble with this question is really just that it's a lot of questions packed together.  To answer one of them: if you know the action of $k$ on $M$, and you know the action of $X$ on $M$, then you know the action of $k[X]$ on $M$, by the other axioms.  For example, if $X\cdot m = f(m)$, then $(2X^2 + 3X + 1)\cdot m = 2\cdot X\cdot X \cdot m + 3\cdot X\cdot m + 1\cdot m = 2f(f(m)) + 3f(m) + m = (2f^2 + 3f + 1)(m)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is because, if $a\in A$, for any $u, v\in V$, we have $a(u+v)=au+av$ and $\cdot 0=0$, by two of the axioms which make up the definition of an $A$-module. So scalar multiplication $m_a$ on $V$ is a group endomorphism, and we have a map 
   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}m \colon A \longrightarrow 
   \End(V),\quad a  \longmapsto(m_a\colon u\mapsto au)$$
   This map is a ring homomorphism, because $m_1=\operatorname{id}_V$, the unit element of $\End(V)$ and $m_{a+b}=m_a+m_b$, which are translations of the axioms $\;1\cdot u=u$ and $\;(a+b)u=au+bu$.
2. Don't forget $x$ is not a variable, but an *indeterminate*: it does not represent an element of $k$, and exists by itself. So it's better to use the formal notation `X`.
   This means we *define* $\; X\cdot u$ as $T(u)$. As we have a ring homomorphism, there follows $\;X^2\cdot u=(T\circ T)(u)=T\bigl(T(u)\bigr)$, and similarly 
   $$X^k\cdot u=(\underbrace{T\circ T\circ \dotsm\circ T}_{k\;\text{factors}})(u) $$
   For a general polynomial, the formula follows by linearity.
3. If multiplication by $X$ is $k$-linear, so it is a $k$-endomoprphism. Why couldn't denote multiplication by $X$ as $T$ when we view it as a vector space endomorphism? Now this pultplication is $k$-linear because, if $\lambda\in k$ and $m\in M$, by the axioms of modules, and commutativity of $k[X]$,
   $$T(\lambda m)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}X(\lambda m)=(X\lambda) m=(\lambda X) m =\lambda (Xm)=\lambda T(m).$$
4. The $k$-linear map $\widehat X$ corresponds to multiplication by $X$. This because a $k$-algebra homomorphism from the ring of polynomials $k[X]$ into a $k$-algebra $E$ is uniquely determined by the image of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer! I'm still sort of confused with my point $4$ above though. Is it possible you could give an example of a $k[x]$-module to elucidate what you mean with point $4$? Sorry to ask for more...

Comment: Any finite dimensional vector space equipped with an endomorphism is such a module, more precisely a *torsion* module. The prototype of such podules are quotients   $k[X]/(F)$ of $k[X]$ by the ideal generated by a polynomial, and direct sums thereof. The motivation for this point of view is that we have very precise theorems for the structures of *finitely generated modules over P.I.D.s*, and  it is intensively used in for the reduction of endomorphisms to *Jordan normal form*, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses question 1 only.

Temporarily forget about the operations of addition on the sets $A$ and $V$.

That is, think of $V$ for the time being as just a set, and $A$ as just a multiplicative monoid.

An action of $A$ on $V$ can be described in two ways, and they are equivalent, in s sense to be explained.

There is an operation of "scalar multiplication", $A \times V \to V$, $(\alpha, v) \mapsto \alpha{v}$, satisfying two postulates:

- $1v = v$, for all $v \in V$.
- $(\alpha\beta)v = \alpha(\beta{v})$, for all $v \in V$ and all $\alpha, \beta \in A$.

We can [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) this function, obtaining a function $\mu: A \to (V \to V)$, where $(V \to V)$ denotes the set of all functions $V \to V$ - if that's not too confusing! - defined by:

- $(\mu(\alpha))(v) = \alpha{v}\ (\alpha \in A$, $v \in V$).

If $\iota$ denotes the identity function $V \to V$, we then have

- $\mu(1) = \iota$,
- $\mu(\alpha\beta) = \mu(\alpha) \circ \mu(\beta)$, for all $\alpha, \beta \in A$.

That is, $\mu$ is a homomorphism of the monoid $A$ into the multiplicative monoid $(V \to V)$ of functions $V \to V$ - sorry about the notation, again! - under the associative operation of function composition, $\circ$.

Conversely, let $\mu: A \to (V \to V)$ be any monoid homomorphism, and define scalar multiplication, $A \times V \to V$, $(\alpha, v) \mapsto \alpha{v}$, by:

- $\alpha{v} = (\mu(\alpha))(v)\ (\alpha \in A$, $v \in V$).

Then the two postulates for scalar multiplication given above are satisfied.

Moreover, if we pass from "scalar multiplication" to "monoid homomorphism" and back again, using these two processes, we get back to the same operation that we started with; ditto, if we pass from "monoid homomorphism" to "scalar multiplication" and back again.

So, there is a kind of equivalence between these two ways of describing an action of a multiplicative monoid $A$ on a set $V$.

If we now recall the operations of addition on $A$ and $V$, we can define the ring $\operatorname{End}(V^+)$ of functions $V \to V$ which respect the operation of addition on $V$; and at the same time, we can specialise to operations of scalar multiplication, $A \times V \to V$, $(\alpha, v) \mapsto \alpha{v}$ satisfying two further postulates:

- $\alpha(v + w) = \alpha{v} + \alpha{w}$, for all $v, w \in V$ and $\alpha \in A$,
- $(\alpha + \beta)v = \alpha{v} + \beta{v}$, for all $\alpha, \beta \in A$ and $v \in V$.

That is:

- $\mu(\alpha) \in \operatorname{End}(V^+)$, for all $\alpha \in A$,
- $\mu(\alpha + \beta) = \mu(\alpha) + \mu(\beta)$, for all $\alpha, \beta \in A$.

Therefore, under the process that has already considered for monoid actions in general, the monoid homomorphism $\mu: A \to (V \to V)$ range-restricts to a monoid homomorphism $A \to \operatorname{End}(V^+)$, which is in fact a ring homomorphism. Conversely, given a ring homomorphism $\mu: A \to \operatorname{End}(V^+)$, and defining scalar multiplication in the same general way as before, we find that the two new postulates are satisfied.

So, the general equivalence between two ways of specifying an action of $A$ on $V$ still holds, and when specialised in the way just described, it becomes an equivalence between: **(1)** operations of scalar multiplication satisfying all the four postulates listed, and **(2)** ring homomorphisms $A \to \operatorname{End}(V^+)$.